# Enable logging for a website via a script

Tags: iis-6, scripting, logging

I'm looking for a way to enable or disable logging for an IIS 6 web site via adsutil.vbs.  Does anyone know which property I need to set?

Thanks

Neil

Answer (score 0):

You can enable/disable logging for the entire W3SVC service using the **LogType** property.  Set it to **0** to disable logging.  This command would disable logging for the W3SVC web service.

```
cscript.exe /nologo adsutil.vbs SET W3SVC/LogType "0"
```

You can also exempt specific child directories or files from logging using the **DontLog** property.  Details for that can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525715.aspx).

Furthermore, you can specify logging at a much more granular level with the adsutil.vbs script and choose specific properties to log using the LogExtFileFlags parameter and corresponding bitmasks.  Just add the values of the bitmasks found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524906.aspx) and set the LogExtFileFlags property.  For example, the following would enable *LogExtFileDate, LogExtFileTime, and LogExtFileHttpSubStatus* (1 + 2 + 2097152 = 2097155)

```
cscript.exe /NoLogo adsutil.vbs SET W3SVC/LogExtFileFlags "2097155"
```